# Jasmine-marbles - Is there a expect(...).ToHaveBeenCalledWithObservable(...) function?

Tags: jasmine, jasmine-marbles

Is there a way to test observable in a function arguments?
Is there any thing like `expect(someObj.foo).ToHaveBeenCalledWithObservable(cold('a|', {a: 1}))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is something that like that but you can maybe take advantage of `callFake` and `toBeObservable`.

We `callFake` and associate a local variable to the argument that was used.

Then we assert the localVariable `toBeObservable` of your expecation.

```
let argumentForFoo: Observable<any>;
spyOn(someObj.foo).and.callFake(argument => argumentForFoo = argument);
// make sure someObj.foo gets called somewhere here so the callFake can run.
expect(argumentForFoo).toBeObservable(/*...*/);
```